# Switch off daylight saving time

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to switch off daylight saving time of my Raspberry Pi.  I am using the Pi for scientific instrumentation. Therefore it needs to keep the same time over the whole year.

I took a look on google and the only thing I could find was this:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=32917

But I don't have that folder, and have no idea where to find the option on my Raspbian Wheezy. Does anyone have an idea where to look? I tried to find it in /usr/share/zoneinfo but had no success.

Comment: Why do you want to turn it off. Is your locale not set correctly? Assuming the issue is similar to the linked post you could just set the TZ to UTC, or use UTC in your progra.m code

Comment: I am using the Pi for scientific instrumentation. Therefore it needs to keep the same time over the whole year.
But I am stupid and forgot that UTC has no summer time at all, so if I put it on UTC it should be fine without adjusting the daylight savings. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your timezone to UTC which does not include daylight savings tome. To do this you can use raspi-config:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Then select option **5 Internationalization Options**.

Next choose **I2 Change Time Zone**

At the bottom of the **Geographic area** list select **None of the above**.

Finally select **UTC** from the list of **Time Zones**, and finish by clicking **OK**

Comment: This is good advice for any server or any instrumentation that will be running 24/7. I've been bitten by this before: when trying to find out why a job didn't run at 02:30, only to realize that there _was_ no 02:30 that night!